# Overlapping annotations in MKMapView swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I have a MKMapview view where there are no of annotations. A location entered by the user is considered as current location. I want this current location to be on top of all other annotations.

Right now, the current location is getting ovwerlapped by other annotations.

I have set the current location annotation displaypriority to required in mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) this method.

Please let me know if there is any other way
I dont want the other annotations to disappear. I just want them overlapped with current location annotation.

Comment: Can you add some code to show how you are adding annotations?

Comment: for count in 0 ..< self.servicesArray.count {
  pinArrayToZoom.append(dropPin)
            mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)

           }
               visibleLocations = pinArrayToZoom
           mapView.showAnnotations(visibleLocations as! [MKAnnotation], animated: true)


 }